# Set up mailserver on windows server 2008 r2 with only dns(no active directory)

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, mx-record

This is a college assignment, for those who don't want to answer those.

I have an environment of 4 virtual machines. 2 Win7 Pro clients, 2 Win2008 r2 servers. All 64-bit.

I have the DNS server role installed on both servers. Servers are 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.4 respectively.

We're "pretending" the first server is geographically in Brussels and the second in Amsterdam.
I've changed the computername of the first server to S1.familyname.eu and the second to amsterdam.familyname.eu, to allow dynamic dns updates.

I've created a primary zone on the first server.

To that I added an MX record with no name, so "same as host". I set 1 A record, "mail", pointing at the MX record. And 2 alias records, "pop" and "smtp", pointing at that A-record.

The course requires us to use [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) as mail server software. On that, I set the domain to "familyname.eu". I made several accounts with simple passwords, but it's not working.

I've tried looking this up, but almost everything I've found is about active directory or linux. The instructor says it should be easy to look this up, but I'm constantly hitting the same wall. I feel throwing my monitor against a wall.

I've installed thunderbird on one of the clients(which has the correct dns server set), and any account I try to add is refused.

I have no idea if I forgot any records, misconfigured them, or whatever.

Here's a link to what the familyname.eu.dns file looks like:

[DNS file contents](http://pastebin.com/aBc5DTZM)

Comment: from one of the client machines, do an `nslookup` from the command prompt and type familyname.eu and hit enter.  What's returned?

Comment: Homework questions are not favoured, but they're not forbidden.  This one, however, is too broad - it could be a DNS issue, it could be something about your hMailServer setup...  Questions here should be answerable, not the start of a trouble-shooting process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually MX records point to a host, rather than the just the domain name. You might want to try changing the MX record to mail.familyname.eu .... In any case you should be able to figure it out from the Linux and AD resources, as they both can implement DNS servers, one's just on a different platform, or with slight enchancements, respectively ....